# How to alter a simple Java Echo Server to be multithreaded?

Tags: java, multithreading

For a task at University we had to alter an example given to:

"Build and test a simple, single-threaded server programme in Java which will accept connections, return the current date and time over that connection and then close the connection."

The majority of us in the class have never used JAVA before and the Lecturer says we can write it any way as long as it works.

I altered the code to produce the following:

```
import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Date;
import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;

public class EchoServer {
        public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {


            int portNumber = 8080;


            try {
                ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(portNumber);

                while(true) {

                    Socket clientSocket = serverSocket.accept();

                    PrintWriter out =
                            new PrintWriter(clientSocket.getOutputStream(), true);

                    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
                            new InputStreamReader(clientSocket.getInputStream()));

                    DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("EEEE dd MMMM yyyy - HH:mm:ss");
                    Date dateobj = new Date();
                    //System.out.println(df.format(dateobj));

                    out.write("HTTP/1.1 200 OK\n\n<html><body>" + "The Date and Time is: " + df.format(dateobj) +
                    "</body></html>");

                    out.close();

                    serverSocket.close();

                    } //while
                }

            catch (IOException e) {
                System.out.println("Oops!");
                System.out.println(e.getMessage());
                }


        } //main

}
```

This works correctly and so I am happy with it.

The next part we have to do is:

" Copy your solution and alter it into a multi-threaded version."

We were given another sample to some multithreaded code:

```
    public class SimpleThread extends Thread{


        protected String threadName;




    public SimpleThread(String name){
        threadName = name;
        }



    public void run(){
            for(int count = 1; count< 100; count++) {
                System.out.println("I am thread " + threadName + ". My count is: " + count);
            //do something slow
            //double result = Math.pow, 1.5);
            }
        }






public static void main(String[] args) {

    System.out.println("Test");


    for (int i = 0; i <10; i++) {
        SimpleThread ste = new SimpleThread("Thread " + i);
        ste.start();
        }


    }

}
```

I have searched for numerous tutorials online and tried to implement the code into mine but I end up just breaking it and it won't compile.

So how can I alter the code to make it multithreaded?

Comment: I'm not a Java guru but didn't you missed `super()` in your constructor?

Comment: (1) Look at when you do `serverSocket.close()`. (2) At the moment `accept()` yields a client socket, you can leave further handling to a thread. Someting like `public SimpleThread(Socket client) {...}`

Comment: The first question to consider is *what parts* of the program's work need to be performed in parallel.  Being multi-threaded does not necessarily mean everything in the whole program runs in parallel.  There are in fact trivial solutions, but the traditional approach would be to set up the socket and accept connections with one thread, and have it spin off a new thread each time it accepts a connection, delegating to that thread responsibility for servicing the request.

Comment: There are multiple examples on the web (search "java multithread socket connection")  es. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/sockets/clientServer.html

Comment: @DavidHaim, it is never necessary for a constructor to invoke `super()` (that is, specifically a no-arg superclass constructor).  Doing so explicitly is optional, and changes nothing, provided no other superclass constructor is explicitly invoked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the first version, you only accept one connection, do things with it, and quit.

The idea here is to accept several connections, that means looping (possibly forever) over :

```
Socket clientSocket = serverSocket.accept();
```

Each time a new *clientSocket* is retrieved this way, you should instantiate a Thread, passing it this *clientSocket*, then running it and let it perform things with the *clientSocket* (reading from, writing to..).

Several of this threads will probably run at the same time.

Comment: The OP would be smart to create those threads with timeouts so you don't run out.  I'd refactor this code to be more modular instead of plopping everything in a main method.  It can be far more general than what's written.

Comment: @Berger Thank you, yes I know this is what I need to do but after following numerous tutorials every time I try to implement the looping it breaks and gives me errors when trying to compile the java file.

The Lecturer just assumed we had all done JAVA before as part of the course but we hadn't. He just gave us the two examples (single threaded and multithreaded) which he said we had to alter.

When he found out we hadn't done any JAVA before he said he would be more lenient when marking.

Comment: Don't hesitate to post your non compiling code with compiler errors, people here will point you to what is wrong .